# I want to cat a file for a list of file names, then search a directory for each of the results and move any files it finds

Tags: linux, xargs

I'm having a really hard time finding an answer for this because most people want to find a list of files, *then* do the xargs.

I have a file with a list of file names. I would like to go through the list of file names in that file and one by one search a single directory (not recursive) and any time it finds the file, move it to a sub folder.

```
cat test.txt | xargs find . -type f -iname
```

At this point, I get this error:
find: paths must precede expression: file1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like:

```
for i in `cat test.txt`
do
    test -e $i && mv <src> <dst>
done
```